# How to combine a variable with '__doc__'?

Tags: python, arcgis

I (Python newby) am working with ArcGIS and want to have a list of all its tools with their full descriptions.
I already got all tool names, using arcpy.ListTools(). But to get the full description is a problem for me.

To get that description I must use a statement such as this one (for the tool 'EmergingHotSpotAnalysis_stpm'):

`arcpy.EmergingHotSpotAnalysis_stpm.__doc__`

But how do I put a variable 'toolname' (for all tool names) in this statement?

`arcpy.+toolname+.__doc__` does not work.

Comment: iterate over the list with a `for` loop: `for tool in tools: tool.__doc__` or what does `ListTools` return? a string? a list of strings? a list of tool objects?

Answer (score 0):

I run this:

```
tools = arcpy.ListTools("*")
for tool in tools:
    usage=arcpy.Usage(tool)
```

The outcome of the variable usage is for instance:

InterpolateShape_3d(in_surface, in_feature_class, out_feature_class, {sample_distance}, {z_factor}, {method}, {DENSIFY | VERTICES_ONLY}, {pyramid_level_resolution})

With the following statement I can get the description of tool InterpolateShape_3d:

```
description=arcpy.InterpolateShape_3d.__doc__
```

This is hardcoded, but I want to do it dynamically. So, from variable usage I extract the part before the (, that's to say InterpolateShape_3d in this example. I put the extract in the variable toolname and then I want to run

```
description=arcpy.+toolname+.__doc__
```

where I get stuck.

How to do this dynamically?